# How can I convert to size_t from int safely?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

Assigning an int to a size_t (or using it in malloc) in GCC produces the following warning:

> warning: conversion to 'size_t' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]

To solve this, I would like to wrap the conversion in a function that first checks if the conversion is valid, then does the cast.

This is what I have so far:

```
/* Convert int src to size_t dst. */
/* Assumes dst points to valid size_t address. */
int safe_size_t_from_int(size_t *dst, int src) {
    if(src < 0) return SAFE_ERROR_NEGATIVE;
    if(SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX) {
        if(src > (int)SIZE_MAX) return SAFE_ERROR_OVERFLOW;
    }
    *dst = (size_t)src;
    return SAFE_SUCCESS;
}
```

Am I missing anything? Is there a library with safe conversions that already exists?

The closest thing I can find is [Microsoft Intsafe.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it appears to be for Win32 types only.

**EDIT** Modified as per chux' comment.

Comment: Why not use `ssize_t`?

Comment: I believe size_t is just an unsigned int on most systems.  Why would you need to typecast it - since src will never be negative: I do not see how you would gain anything from the typecast.

Comment: @Carlise it depends on the architecture, on my x86_64 and `glibc` it is `unsigned long int`.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point in having a function for this. No sane system that I know of has an `INT_MAX` that can overflow a `size_t`, so the net effect is that you replaced a "is this value negative" check with "did this function succeed" check.

Comment: @iharob - okay right - but I still don't understand why you would need to typecast it

Comment: @Carlise Because certain functions take size_t and you have an int for example. Checking it will fit is a good thing.

Comment: @2501 - I see; I was thinking it from the other way; casting a size_t to an int.  I need to work on my attention to details.

Comment: I was taught that in a strongly typed language such as C you should always cast from a different type and not just assume the compiler will handle it for you. One reason is to take care of compiler warnings. I was also taught to enable all warnings and deal with every one. And one reason for *that* is if you get a new warning amongst a horde that you think are OK, you might miss it.

Comment: As far as I know of, you're not guaranteed that sizeof(size_t) >= sizeof(int). So all the check you make there make sense to me. Note that you can optimize your code by doing the check by precompiler directives (#if INT_MAX > SIZE_MAX ... ). You may want to consider using fixed size integral types (stdint.h)

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's definitely an area on which folks disagree, but I would say you should never cast except when necessary. Casts are a code smell (usually bugs) and having gratuitous casts all over the place makes it a lot more work to check for erroneous ones.

Comment: @R.. I don't go overboard on that. For example I don't cast between `char` and `int` except to remove (benign) warnings - indeed many `char` functions take and return `int`, for example `toupper()`. But I do modify to remove all warnings from a pukka piece of code. Example `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));`

Comment: @R.. In MS Visual C, where `int i=1, j=3;`, `float f=i/j;` issues a compiler warning but `double d=i/j;` does not, however both give result 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's MSVC's problem...

Comment: @R.. it's the problem of those who have to use it.

Comment: @davak if SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX on a given platform, I would expect that platform's compiler to optimize the second check out.

Comment: Why would you use `int` in a place that requires `size_t` in the first place?

Comment: @n.m. A third party library gives me a size as an int, I want to malloc that many bytes, but malloc requires a size_t.

Comment: 1) suggest moving this post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  2) `if(SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX) {` should be `if(SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX) {`.  No reason for the check if they are equal.

Answer (score 10):

To avoid compiler warnings in GCC, limit the action performed by a single cast operation to one of the following:

1. truncation or extension
2. cast away signed-ness or unsigned-ness
3. cast away const-ness or non-const-ness

size_t is always an unsigned type large enough to hold a void pointer. Casting from
int to size_t involves two cast operations: extend, then cast away signed-ness.

Here's two functions that produce no compiler warnings (with '-Wall -Werror -Wextra') on GCC 4.8.3. They return failure inline (via sentinel values), rather than in an extra return parameter.

```
int size_t2int(size_t val) {
    return (val <= INT_MAX) ? (int)((ssize_t)val) : -1;
}

size_t int2size_t(int val) {
    return (val < 0) ? __SIZE_MAX__ : (size_t)((unsigned)val);
}
```

Comment: Besides the sentinel return, int2size seems to do almost the same thing as my function. However, it assumes that INT_MAX <= SIZE_MAX. Is that guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, this code assumes that (sizeof(size_t) >= sizeof(int)). I suppose there could be a platform where that test fails, but I do not know of one.

Comment: For those who, like me, don't know ssize_t is guaranteed to hold values from at least -1 to __SIZE_MAX__. So casting val to ssize_t gets rid of the unsigned-ness.