# How to convert size_t to int in C?

Tags: c, c99

Is it possible to safely convert a variable with type `size_t` to type `int` in C99?

I appreciate that `size_t` in unsigned, but in the case where we need an `int` representation, what can we do?

Comment: There is no safe conversion. Just use casting.

Comment: You can safely convert `size_t` to `int` by checking its range before casting it. If it is outside the valid `int` range, you can't.

Comment: Test against INT_MAX to ensure no possible signed integer overflow before casting it. If that pans out, just cast and run with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert to size\_t from int safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490762/how-can-i-convert-to-size-t-from-int-safely)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to safely convert a variable with type size_t to type
> int in C99?

It depends on what you mean by "safely".

The maximum representable value of type `size_t`
is typically larger than the maximum representable value of type `int`.  If you are asking whether all `size_t` values can be converted to type `int` without losing information then the answer is probably "no" for your implementation, and definitely "no" in a portability sense.

If you are asking whether it is possible to detect that a `size_t` value is too large for type `int` without actually trying to perform an explicit conversion, so as to avoid the implementation-defined result and possible signal in the event that the value is out of range and fall back to some kind of graceful failure, then the answer is "yes".  You can safely compare the value in question with `INT_MAX`.  Suitable value-preserving conversions will be applied automatically to bring the operands of the `<=` or `>` operator to a common type, and the operation will yield the appropriate result.

> I appreciate that size_t in unsigned, but in the case where we need an
> int representation, what can we do?

If you're just asking about syntax, assuming that the values you want to convert will always be representable as type `int`, then you can cast (`int x; x  = (int) my_size_t_value;`), but you don't actually need to do anything at all in some contexts.  In particular, you can directly assign a `size_t` to an `int` variable, or directly pass it to an `int` parameter of a non-variadic function with an in-scope prototype, and in those cases the appropriate conversion will be performed automatically.

Comment: In my situation, this answer resolved some `warnings` in the build. (`this->total_cases = (int) this->cases_database.rows();`)